# Is there a way to edit cloudwatch log events?

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch

We use ECS Fargate and application logs are sent to AWS Cloudwatch. We discovered that there are some data we don't want to be visible in our logs and are trying to edit our existing cloudwatch logs to remove those data. Is it possible? If not, what's our alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, depending on tradeoffs you prefer:

- Cloudwatch logs can not be edited but they can be deleted. Load the log stream, filter the data and dump into a S3 bucket. Log analytics is tricky at the starting because logs will live in two places - S3 and Cloudwatch. (You can also print/log the filtered log stream from Lambda and so it will show up in Cloudwatch under a Lambda log group but the timestamps will be different. You can preserve timestamp by dumping in S3).
- If you can, decrease retention period of logs and encrypt it so it is hard to access. This can hinder daily operations because logs are hard to access.

Logs ideally should not be tampered with. I think the reason logs can not be edited is because a distributed highly scaleable and available append-only storage/database is a lot cheaper and easier to run than a counter-part with update (you run into all kinds of problems. CAP theorum in short).

Answer (score -1):

You can use lambda and then modify the logs or edit the logs and then push back to cloudwatch to new loggroup for example called modified-loggroup.

Other Option You can mask the sensitive data in Cloudwatch

Comment: Masked data can be unmasked on Cloudwatch in a few ways. Not recommended for data that should not be in Cloudwatch to start with.

Comment: Unmasking can only be done if someone have IAM permissions for unmasking so this is something that can be controlled by the owner.

Comment: If something should not be in cloudwatch, using IAM roles to remove access is not the solution. It is lazy and in practice goes very quickly in many ways.